# xtext: detecting when mouse over a token in editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext

I want to achieve following functionality:

User places the mouse cursor over a text item in the editor and this is being detected automatically, triggering a menu item to be enabled in the menu (when user moves mouse away, the menu item is disabled again).

As I'm a little new to xtext and RCP in general, I don't know where to start. I only don't know how to implement detecting if the cursor is over a certain element in my DSL code. Is there any way to achieve this?

Kind regards,
Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, XText support hover detection. There are some sources in internet, that might be helpful for you.

- http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/hover-support-in-xtext-2-0-tutorial/
- http://ckulla.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/hover-support-in-xtext-2-0/
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/452862/1008201/#msg_1008201